# Issue using formGroup and formArray for UI

Tags: angular, angular5, formarray, formgroups

I have trouble using formArray and formGroup UI shared below.

[image: UI]

Code

Rudimentary component.html file

```
<section class="sampleForm">
<div class="panel">
    <p class="sample-setup-breadcrumbs">
        <a routerLink="/communicationSuite/samples" class="muted-text"> Q & A Listing </a>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-righta smaller-text muted-text"></i>
        Setup
    </p>

    <div *ngIf="errorOnPage" class="alert alert-danger fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" (click)="errorOnPage=false">&times;</a>
        <strong>Error!</strong> {{pageError}}
    </div>
    <form *ngIf="sampleFormGroup"
          [formGroup]="sampleFormGroup"
          (click)="dirtyFormCheck(sampleFormGroup.dirty)"
          (keyup)="dirtyFormCheck(sampleFormGroup.dirty)"
          class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Name</h4>
        </div>
        <section class="panel-body show-overflow">
            <div class="row col-sm-7">
                <div class="flex-display flex-space-between">
                    <h5 class="muted-text control-header-text">Q & A Name<span class="required">*</span></h5>
                    <label id="nameCharCounter" class="details-text-counter-label muted-text">
                        {{ (sampleFormGroup.controls.sampleName?.value?.length || 0) }} / {{ this.nameMaxLength }}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control text-form-control"
                       formControlName="sampleName" id="sampleName" name="sampleName"
                       value="{{ this.sampleName }}" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false"
                       maxlength="{{ this.nameMaxLength }}" placeholder="Enter Q & A Name" required="required" />

                <div *ngIf="sampleFormGroup && sampleFormGroup.controls.sampleName?.invalid && (sampleFormGroup.controls.sampleName?.dirty || sampleFormGroup.controls.sampleName?.touched)" class="required">sample Name is required.</div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Question & Answer<span class="required">*</span></h4>
        </div>
        <section class="panel-body show-overflow">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="flex-display flex-space-between">
                        <h5 class="muted-text control-header-text">Question Text<span class="required">*</span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control text-form-control"
                           formControlName="questionTitle" id="questionTitle" name="questionTitle"
                           value="{{ this.questionTitle }}" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false" maxlength="{{ this.questionsLength}}}"
                           placeholder="Enter Question Here" required="required" />

                    <div *ngIf="sampleFormGroup && sampleFormGroup.controls.questionTitle?.invalid && (sampleFormGroup.controls.questionTitle?.dirty || sampleFormGroup.controls.questionTitle?.touched)" class="required">sample Question is required.</div>

                    <div class="flex-display flex-space-between">
                        <h5 class="muted-text control-header-text">Answer Type<span class="required">*</span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <!--<select class="form-control" name="questionType" id="questionType" formControlName="questionType">-->
                    <!--<option class="muted-text" ng-selected="this.questionType === 'SINGLE_CHOICE'"> Single Select on Answer Choices </option>-->
                    <!--<option class="muted-text" ng-selected="this.questionType === 'MULTIPLE_CHOICE'"> Multiple Select on Answer Choices</option>-->
                    <!--</select>-->
                    <select class="form-control" name="questionType" id="questionType" formControlName="questionType">
                        <option *ngFor="let questionType of questionTypes" [value]="questionType" class="muted-text">
                            {{ questionType}}
                        </option>
                    </select>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="flex-display flex-space-between">
                        <h5 class="muted-text control-header-text">Answer Choices<span class="required">*</span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control text-form-control"
                           formControlName="answerText1" id="answerText1" name="answerText1"
                           value="{{ this.answerText1 }}" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false" maxlength="{{ this.answersLength}}}}"
                           placeholder="Answer Choice 1" required="required" />

                    <div *ngIf="sampleFormGroup && sampleFormGroup.controls.answerText1?.invalid && (sampleFormGroup.controls.answerText1?.dirty || sampleFormGroup.controls.answerText1?.touched)" class="required">At least two answer are required.</div>

                    <input class="form-control text-form-control"
                           formControlName="answerText2" id="answerText2" name="answerText2"
                           value="{{ this.answerText2 }}" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false" maxlength="{{ this.answersLength}}}}"
                           placeholder="Answer Choice 2" required="required" />

                    <div *ngIf="sampleFormGroup && sampleFormGroup.controls.answerText2?.invalid && (sampleFormGroup.controls.answerText2?.dirty || sampleFormGroup.controls.answerText2?.touched)" class="required">At least two answer are required.</div>

                    <input class="form-control text-form-control"
                           formControlName="answerText3" id="answerText3" name="answerText3"
                           value="{{ this.answerText3 }}" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false" maxlength="{{ this.answersLength}}}}"
                           placeholder="Answer Choice 3" />


                    <input class="form-control text-form-control"
                           formControlName="answerText4" id="answerText4" name="answerText4"
                           value="{{ this.answerText4 }}" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false" maxlength="{{ this.answersLength}}}}"
                           placeholder="Answer Choice 4" />


                    <input class="form-control text-form-control"
                           formControlName="answerText5" id="answerText5" name="answerText5"
                           value="{{ this.answerText5 }}" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false" maxlength="{{ this.answersLength}}}}"
                           placeholder="Answer Choice 5" />

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="flex-display flex-space-between">
                        <h5 class="muted-text control-header-text">Confirmation Message<span class="required">*</span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control text-form-control"
                           formControlName="confirmationMessage" id="confirmationMessage" name="confirmationMessage"
                           value="{{ this.confirmationMessage }}" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false"
                           maxlength="{{ this.confirmationMessageLength }}" placeholder="Type your confirmation message here" required="required" />

                    <div *ngIf="sampleFormGroup && sampleFormGroup.controls.confirmationMessage?.invalid && (sampleFormGroup.controls.confirmationMessage?.dirty || sampleFormGroup.controls.confirmationMessage?.touched)" class="required">Confirmation Message is required.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>


        <div>All fields required.</div>
        <div class="form-actions btn-container-botton extra-padding">
            <a [routerLink]="['']" class="btn page-secondary-action-btn customer-instance-button">CANCEL</a>
            <button [disabled]="!(sampleFormGroup.valid)" class="btn page-primary-action-btn" type="button" (click)="savesample()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

I have trouble initializing form using formArray, formGroup for above UI. Could you please someone help with how to correctly initialize this form?

Sample post body looks below. If you notics, questions[] is an array in model not an objet though it is already once used in UI.

```
{
"samples": [
    {
        "id": 95,
        "name": "Test Self Attestation",
        "type": "SelfAttestation",
        "employerKey": "castlight",
        "externalKey": "test_self_attestation_20190314065907650_9127",
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": 2404,
                "title": "How would you rate your health?",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "displayOrder": 0,
                        "text": "Excellent",
                        "externalKey": "excellent_20190314065907792_9961",
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "displayOrder": 1,
                        "text": "Good",
                        "externalKey": "good_20190314065907792_6599",
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "displayOrder": 2,
                        "text": "OK",
                        "externalKey": "ok_20190314065907792_6746",
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "displayOrder": 3,
                        "text": "Bad",
                        "externalKey": "bad_20190314065907792_9591",
                        "selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "displayOrder": 4,
                        "text": "Terrible",
                        "externalKey": "terrible_20190314065907792_1418",
                        "selected": false
                    }
                ],
                "topicName": "Other",
                "topicId": 0,
                "externalKey": "how_would_you_rate_your_health_20190314065907650_7168",
                "isTemplateQuestion": false,
                "question_type": "SINGLE_CHOICE"
            }
        ],
        "confirmationMessage": "Self Attestation completed successfully"
      }
],
"pagination": {
    "page": 0,
    "per_page": 1000,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "total_count": 8
}
```

}

Comment: will you please create a stackblitz so that we can help fast

Comment: can you show us your component's code?

Comment: Sure. give me a moment please.

Comment: @Arikael https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryzjs5

Comment: @SheikAlthaf https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryzjs5

Comment: Stackblitz ain't working coz of formGroup errors

Comment: Hello. Have you imported the ReactiveFormsModule in your AppModule?

Comment: Yes, it's there. I need help me in creating this formgroup

Comment: your stackblitz has a lot of issues unrelated to the posted question.
you missing ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule, InjectionToken ToastConfig.

Can you fix your stackblitz?